# how to specify which R lib to use when installing a R package?

Tags: r, xml, libxml2

[I was trying to use a R package called "XML"](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/93152/#93226), 
but had trouble to use it after installation:

```
# in R environment
> library("XML")
> XML::parseURI("")
Error in XML::parseURI("") : cannot parse URI
```

the issue turned out to be that R could not find the current version of "libxml2" installed in my directory:

```
 echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH /somewhere/Jun/Programme/libxml2-devel-2.9.1-2.1/usr/lib/:
```

retrieve information about the version of the libxml2 library "XML" linking to

```
> path = unclass(getLoadedDLLs()[["XML"]])$path
> path
[1] "/misc/home/Jun/Programme/R-3.3.1/lib64/R/library/XML/libs/XML.so"
> system2("ldd",args=path)
                linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff2a9e8000)
                libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2 (0x00002aefc088a000)  # XML is using a common "libxml2.so.2" not the one I installed. 
                libz.so.1 => //home/Jun/Programme/zlib-1.2.11/lib/libz.so.1 (0x00002aefc0bc8000)
                libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002aefc0de5000)
                libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00002aefc1068000)
                ...
```

Any suggestion to do that?

in order to make "XML" link to the libxml2 installed in my directory, 
I made such efforts:

1. setting PATH for libxml2:

   echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

   /somewhere/Jun/Programme/pcre-8.40/lib/:/somewhere/Jun/Programme/xz-5.2.3/lib/:/somewhere/Jun/Programme/zlib-1.2.11/include/:/somewhere/Jun/Programme/zlib-1.2.11/lib/:/somewhere/Jun/Programme/bzip2-1.0.6/lib/:/somewhere/Jun/Programme/bzip2-1.0.6/include/:/somewhere/Jun/Programme/gcc-6.1.0/lib/:/somewhere/Jun/Programme/gcc-6.1.0/lib64/:/somewhere/Jun/Programme/libxml2-devel-2.9.1-2.1/usr/lib/:/somewhere/Jun/Programme/curl-7.52.1/lib/:/somewhere/Jun/Programme/libtool_CentOS6_64/usr/lib64/:/home/appl/openmpi-1.3.1/lib:/opt22/lsf83_exp/8.3/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/lib:/opt/ups/lib
2. recompile R with configuration specifying lib using "--enable" argument

   ./configure --prefix=$HOME/Programme/R-3.3.1 --enable-R-shlib LDFLAGS="-L/$HOME/Programme/zlib-1.2.11/lib -L/$HOME/Programme/bzip2-1.0.6/lib -L/$HOME/Programme/xz-5.2.3/lib -L/$HOME/Programme/pcre-8.40/lib -L/$HOME/Programme/curl-7.52.1/lib " CPPFLAGS="-I/$HOME/Programme/zlib-1.2.11/include -I/$HOME/Programme/bzip2-1.0.6/include -I/$HOME/Programme/xz-5.2.3/include -I/$HOME/Programme/pcre-8.40/include -I/$HOME/Programme/curl-7.52.1/include"
3. install "XML" with configure arguments:

   biocLite("XML",configure.args='--with-xml-    config="/somewhere/Jun/Programme/libxml2-devel-2.9.1-2.1/usr/bin/xml2-config"')
   BioC_mirror: http://bioconductor.org
   Using Bioconductor 3.4 (BiocInstaller 1.24.0), R 3.3.1 (2016-06-21).
   Installing package(s) ‘XML’
   trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/XML_3.98-1.5.tar.gz'

   ## Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1599213 bytes (1.5 MB)

   downloaded 1.5 MB
   ...

but none of them seemed to work:

```
* installing *source* package ‘XML’ ...
** package ‘XML’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for sed... /bin/sed
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
User defined xml-config: /somewhere/Jun/Programme/libxml2-devel-2.9.1-2.1/usr/bin/xml2-config, XML Version: 2, XML2: yes
USE_XML2 = yes
SED_EXTENDED_ARG: -r
Minor 9, Patch 1 for 2.9.1
Located parser file -I/usr/include/libxml2/parser.h
checking for gzopen in -lz... yes
checking for xmlParseFile in -lxml2... yes
checking for xmlHashSize in -lxml2... yes
Using built-in xmlHashSize
Checking DTD parsing (presence of externalSubset)...
checking for xmlHashSize in -lxml2... yes
Found xmlHashSize
checking for xmlOutputBufferCreateBuffer in -lxml2... yes
have xmlOutputBufferCreateBuffer()
checking for xmlDocDumpFormatMemoryEnc in -lxml2... yes
checking libxml/xmlversion.h usability... yes
checking libxml/xmlversion.h presence... yes
checking for libxml/xmlversion.h... yes
Expat:  FALSE
Checking for return type of xmlHashScan element routine.
No return value for xmlHashScan
xmlNs has a context field
Checking for cetype_t enumeration
Using recent version of R with cetype_t enumeration type for encoding
checking for xmlsec1-config... /usr/bin/xmlsec1-config
nodegc default 
xml-debug default 
No XML_WITH_ZLIB enumeration value.
Version has xmlHasFeature()

****************************************
Configuration information:

Libxml settings

libxml include directory: -I/usr/include/libxml2
libxml library directory: -lxml2 -lz -lm -ldl -lz  -lxml2
libxml 2:                 -DLIBXML2=1
```

Comment: What's the output of `/somewhere/Jun/Programme/libxml2-devel-2.9.1-2.1/usr/bin/xml2-config --cflags --libs`?

Comment: @nwellnhof, hi nwellnhof , as you might suspect,  `xml2-config --cflags
-I/usr/include/libxml2 
xml2-config --libs
-lxml2 -lz -lm -ldl  # the xml2-config points at the system libraries. ` my xml2-config did not point to the lib I installed. I resolved my issue by reinstallation by compiling  instead of using "rpm". Thanks for your attention and suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the solution. Instead of using rpm to install "libxml2"
(I apologize that I did not mention it in my post; I didn't realize that it could be the cause of my trouble), I ought to have compiled "libxml2" from source.

For people that have a similar issue:

Download the current version of libxml2 http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/libxml2.html,

following the instructions of the link above.

Two points for installation:

1.

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/Programme --disable-static --with-history --with-zlib=/somewhere/Jun/Programme/zlib-1.2.11 && make
```

you have to specify zlib (--with); this also means that you have to have zlib installed. I had to add "--with" to make `configure` work.

2. The instructions state that you have to call "make install" as root user, but no, you don't have to do this.
3. Set the `PATH` for your installed "libxml2".
4. Reinstall your R package "XML".